# Paths not drawn after dragging in parallel coordinate in d3 V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is a simple parallel coordinate in d3 V4 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ejg7CI7STPqXKB2tot51?p=preview

It is similar to https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281 , which is in V3.

Following are the steps to reproduce the issue:
Step1. Brush some area (say 0.8 to 0.4) in column1.... 
Step2. Brush some area (say 0.7 to 0.4) in column3....
Step3. Now drag the axis column3 to the position of column2. (So basically axis ordering will get changed, from Column1, 2 , 3, 4 .. it will change to column1, 3 ,2, 4.

Step4. Brush column3 (which is now next to column1) again. You will see no paths are being drawn.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.background path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
   stroke-opacity: .4;  
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.foreground path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-opacity: .7;
}

.brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .3;
  stroke: #fff;

  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  cursor: move;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>


var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scalePoint().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(1),
    y = {},
    dragging = {};


var line = d3.line(),
    //axis = d3.axisLeft(x),
    background,
    foreground,
    extents;


 var container = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "parcoords")
    .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
    .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");

var svg = container.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var quant_p = function(v){return (parseFloat(v) == v) || (v == "")};     

d3.json("convertcsvSO.json", function(error, cars) {

    dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]);

    x.domain(dimensions);

    dimensions.forEach(function(d) {
    var vals = cars.map(function(p) {return p[d];});
    if (vals.every(quant_p)){ 
     y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { 
            return +p[d]; }))
        .range([height, 0])


      }
    else{
     vals.sort();           
      y[d] = d3.scalePoint()
              .domain(vals.filter(function(v, i) {return vals.indexOf(v) == i;}))
              .range([height, 0],1);
       }

  })


 extents = dimensions.map(function(p) { return [0,0]; });


  // Add grey background lines for context.
  background = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "background")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  // Add blue foreground lines for focus.
  foreground = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);



  // Add a group element for each dimension.

  var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
      .data(dimensions)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "dimension")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {  return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .subject(function(d) { return {x: x(d)}; })
        .on("start", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = x(d);
          background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
        })
        .on("drag", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
          foreground.attr("d", path);
          dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return position(a) - position(b); });
          x.domain(dimensions);
          g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + position(d) + ")"; })
        })
        .on("end", function(d) {
          delete dragging[d];
          transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
          transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
          background
              .attr("d", path)
            .transition()
              .delay(500)
              .duration(0)
              .attr("visibility", null);
        }));


  // Add an axis and title.
   var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension");
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d) {  d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(y[d]));})
      //text does not show up because previous line breaks somehow
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9) 
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  // Add and store a brush for each axis.
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        if(y[d].name == 'r'){
         // console.log(this);

        d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY().extent([[-8, 0], [8,height]]).on("start", brushstart).on("brush", brush_parallel_chart));
        }
        })
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);  
});  // closing

function position(d) {
  var v = dragging[d];
  return v == null ? x(d) : v;
}

function transition(g) {
  return g.transition().duration(500);
}

// Returns the path for a given data point.
function path(d) {
  return line(dimensions.map(function(p) { return [position(p), y[p](d[p])]; }));
}


// brush start function
function brushstart() {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}


// Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
function brush_parallel_chart() {

    for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){

            if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {
                  extents[i]=d3.event.selection.map(y[dimensions[i]].invert,y[dimensions[i]]);
                  }
    }

     foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
            if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
                return true;
            }
          return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
        }) ? null : "none";
      }); 
}    


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `drag` callbacks, the **dimensions** are being sorted BUT the **extents** aren't. I've added a few lines that sorts **extents** array based on the new dimensions (by using `origDimensions` which is the original array)

Here's a fork of your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/DquAXNv2mbbok7ssNuoX?p=preview

**Relevant code:**

```
var origDimensions = dimensions.slice(0);
```

And within the `dragend` callback:

```
// one way of sorting the extents array based on dimensions
var new_extents = [];
for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){
     new_extents.push(extents[origDimensions.indexOf(dimensions[i])]);
}
extents = new_extents;
origDimensions = dimensions.slice(0); // setting origDimensions to the new array
```

Hope this helps. (and btw seems like the `brushstart` is empty which leads to showing NO curves on brush reset - try resetting brush on any axis).